# Logs are not printing

Tags: java, log4j, springjunit4classrunner

I am currently working on a project which has spring used in it.
For Junit, i am using @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) annotation. Everything is working fine except I do not see any logs for spring processing of applicationContext.
In the console window, this is a current message :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have kept the log4j.properties in src/main/resources folder of Eclipse(Using a maven project).
Following are the contents :

Log4j.properties ;

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%p\t%d{ISO8601}\t%r\t%c
\t[%t]\t%m%n
```

Have looked at already raised Q/A regarding similar issues. But still no clue about what is the issue. Could anyone here help me please in this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the where the log4j properties are stored as a context param of your spring application. You can done by adding the following part inside your web.xml. Make sure you bundle  log4j.properties file inside your /WEB-INF/classes/ directory.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I am afraid that I do not have a web-app setup ready. I am currently building up the services and testing those parallely using Junit. Is there any property similar as you have adviced i can configure with Junit ?

Comment: To use in the unit testing you need to initialize the logger inside the test class. Here's a good reference on how you do it. http://robertmaldon.blogspot.com/2007/09/programmatically-configuring-log4j-and.html